# How to extend a website with a calculated column?

Tags: html, dynamic

I actually don't know what I could search for, so I need advice in technology. So what do I want?

Imagine you are visiting a website and you see a table/div combination like this:

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="price1">
    <span>100$</span>
  </div>
  <div class="quantity">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have a price and a quantity of an article and you want to calculate the sum (300$) dynamically and add the result somewhere on the website (one column more for example).

**What can I do to achieve this dynamically like using a browser debugging tool like Firebug?**
I don't want to make a Java Application with an InputStream.

(Note that I do not own the website!)

Comment: Well, using Excel and copy & paste stuff. 
But as I told I'm looking for a technology to add
elements into a website I'm not the owner of.
If I would know WHAT to use, then I would have tried something. That's why I ask for help/ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust a page that way you need to modify it using [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JavaScript).

Regarding your example, to add the sum after the price and quantity you could have a script like this:

```js
let price = Number.parseFloat(document.querySelector(".price1 > span").textContent);
let quantity = Number.parseFloat(document.querySelector(".quantity > span").textContent);
let a = document.querySelector(".a");

let sum = document.createElement("div");
sum.textContent = price * quantity;

a.appendChild(sum);
```

This script can be executed with the command line of the browser debugging tool.

Though note that this change is only temporary. It will be gone again the next time you access the website or reload it. To apply the script everytime the page is loaded you can use a browser add-on like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?src=stackoverflow), which allows to automatically execute your script on specific pages.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly I was looking for. I'm still open to easier/another solutions.